# Using Tkinter Listbox as an alternative to printing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

I'm making a GUI program with Tkinter, and made a Listbox in order to print some sentences in there, I've used the .insert method of Listbox but the thing is, the program runs in the background and then prints everything together, which A makes a lag problem and B it's not what I intended. Now the thing that I want to achieve is to insert each item as soon as it's triggered in the code, so for example : l1.insert(END,'Hi') ---- a=1+1 ---- l1.insert(END,'Hi again')
I want the 'Hi' to be visible in the listbox and then the program calculates a, after that inserts 'Hi again', and not does everything and prints all at once.
Is this possible or should I look for another method ? Please specify some methods that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looking to run computations in the background of a GUI application you need to use multithreading or multiprocessing. This is because your GUI will freeze while waiting for the function to run. These processes are made easier if you build your GUI with an OOP (object oriented programming) structure. Using OOP will make it so you can pass your GUI to your thread, and as soon as it is ready it will write "HI" or "Hi again" without creating a lag problem. Here is an example of a simple OOP threaded GUI I made.

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import time
import datetime


class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.win.geometry(newGeometry="%dx%d%+d%+d" % (45, 40, 50, 50))
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.current_pay = tk.StringVar()
        self.time_output = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self.win, textvariable=self.time_output, bg="#450609", fg='white').pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        tk.Label(self.win, textvariable=self.current_pay, bg="#450609", fg='white').pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        self.create_thread()

    def calculate_pay(self):
        pay_rate = 2000.00 #made up hourly wage for Stack Overflow post
        now = time.time()
        elapsed = datetime.timedelta(seconds=(now - self.start_time))
        hours = int(elapsed.seconds/3600)
        minutes = int(((elapsed.seconds / 3600) - hours) * 60)
        seconds = int(((((elapsed.seconds / 3600) - hours) * 60) - minutes) * 60)
        self.current_pay.set('$%.2f' % ((elapsed.seconds / 3600) * pay_rate))
        self.time_output.set('{}:{}:{}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds))

    def method_in_a_thread(self):
        while True:
            self.calculate_pay()
            time.sleep(.3)
            self.win.lift()

    def create_thread(self):
        self.run_thread = Thread(target=self.method_in_a_thread)
        self.run_thread.start()


app = OOP()
app.win.mainloop()
```

This GUI has been adapted for posting purposes on several lines, but I think can help show you how I create a thread that runs forever (yours doesn't have to by any means) and uses that thread to update the GUI that is visible! In less than 50 lines you can have a clock that shows how long you've been at work and how much money you've made thus far in the day XD!

Comment: okay I am looking for something similar to this, and my project isn't about calculation, I just wanted to simplify the example. I have a while loop and as soon as a condition is met it should insert in the listbox, also im kinda week at OOP, is there any other method ?

Comment: @MohammadHalawi You definitely need a separate thread or process to not freeze the GUI. You don't need to use OOP though, although I think it makes it easier to pass variables to your thread. You could always do something like `t = threading.Thread(target=some_calculating_function, args=[your_arguments])`

Comment: Thank you so much, and I have found an example that suited me based on your suggestions.

Comment: @MohammadHalawi No problem! Glad I could help XD